# Perfect square with perfect digits within a range

Tags: c

What is the best way to get all the perfect squares with perfect digits between a range [a,b]? 
A perfect digit perfect square is the one with all its digits perfect squares.
I did as follows

```
for j=a to b
    do if(checkPerfectSquare(j) && checkPerfectDigit(j))
        then ctr++
print ctr

int checkPerfectSquare(n)
{
if n<0
    return 0
root=round(sqrt(n))
return (n==root*root)
}

int checkPerfectDigit(n)
{
while n>0
    do rem=n%10
       n=n/10
    if(!checkPerfectSquare(rem))
        return 0
return 1
}
```

Comment: That is interesting pseudo-code, but have you actually tried to implement this? if yes what is your issue with it? Also if you are using `int` then you do not need to round.

Comment: You've got some problems...In `checkPerfectSquare()`, you have `i` as an argument but after checking it, you use `n` instead of `i`.  In `checkPerfectDigit()`, you don't use the argument `j` at all. You should not be writing C that assumes `i` and `j` are `int`; that was archaic before the C89 standard was made.

Comment: I also believe that in `checkPerfectDigit` there is an endless loop, as n never gets changed?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change n,but I've editted the code.

Comment: @UnholySheep The problem is that it is exceeding in time.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo code you provide seems correct -- except for typos like `i` and `n` in `checkPerfectSquare`. If your implementation gives unexpected results, please show your real code.

Okay here let us review your purpose: to select perfect square with perfect digits inside range [a,b]. Here is a simple idea:

- To iterate through the range [a,b] and test each of the numbers. Actually this is exactly what you do. This gives correct answers of course, but please notice when `a` and `b` become large your problem would suffer from very low efficiency.

Notice that there're always fewer squares than all numbers in a range, we could do this:

- To iterate through all perfect squares inside [a,b] and test whether they are made of perfect digits. How would this be? Inside the range of `[10^(n-1), 10^n-1]` (range of all n-digit numbers) there are merely about `10^(n/2) - 10^((n-1)/2)` perfect squares! This is much smaller than the amount of numbers in this whole range, and as a result your program would run faster.

Well, if you're agreed with the above idea, you may write a better program. But wait, let's try reverse the order this time. Notice that there is actually only three perfect digits: `1 4` and `9`, we may optimize the original idea like this:

- To iterate through all numbers that are made of perfect digits (e.g. 1111111, 149149149, 111144449999) inside the range of [a,b], and test whether they are perfect squares. This would obviously run faster since there are `10^n` numbers with n digits, while only `3^n` with n perfect digits. This would be better than the idea above since `3^n` = `9^(n/2)` < `10^(n/2)`

I'm not providing any pseudo or real code here for now. You may want to understand the ideas and try write some code first.

Comment: Now I'm trying like this
for j=sqrt(a) to sqrt(b)
    do if(j*j>=a)
            if(checkPerfectDigit(j*j)
            {
                if(checkPerfect(j*j))

                    ctr++;
            }

        }
in this approach loop searches between the square root of the ranges.But now the online compiler is showing wrong answer. But i'm getting the right answer for the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
count=((floor(sqrt(b))-ceil(sqrt(a)))+1);
```